# SPQuery and RowLimit

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, object-model, splistitem, spquery

I have around 10000+ rows(Listitems)  in a list I want to query.

I want to iterate each of the item in a timerJob - but I cant take all of them at a time 
since : Object Model Override - NO,  ListView threshold - 1000  - in the FARM level and i we cant change this.

What is the way for me to iterate all the 10000+ (like a batch) ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a [ContentIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee562948.aspx). This will allow you to iterate over the contents of very large lists without triggering an `SPQueryThrottledException`.

For example:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["MyList"];

// Build query using an iterator-defined WHERE clause
string query = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MyFieldName'/><Value Type='Text'>MyFieldValue</Value></Eq></Where>{0}", ContentIterator.ItemEnumerationOrderByNVPField);

// Instantiate iterator and use it to process the list
ContentIterator iterator = new ContentIterator();
iterator.ProcessListItems(list, query, ProcessListItem, ProcessListItemError);
```

Then you'd define your `ProcessListItem` and `ProcessListItemError` thusly:

```
static void ProcessListItem(SPListItem item) {
    Console.WriteLine("ProcessListItem: Name {0}", item.Title);
}

static bool ProcessListItemError(SPListItem item, Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: message {0}", e.Message);
    return true;
}
```

I'd also recommend you review Microsoft's [Best Practices with SharePoint Server articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff660756), in particular "[Writing Efficient Code In SharePoint Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558807%28v=office.14%29.aspx)", which further discusses properly writing queries.